# Why is bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect: creating an empty image?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbitmapimagerep

I have a very simple bit of code that is supposed to capture the bitmap of a view.  This used to work in Leopard, but seems horribly broken in Snow Leopard.

Here is the code, responding to a button press on the window:

```
- (IBAction)snapshot:(id)sender
{
    NSView* view = [[sender window] contentView];
    NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap
        = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[view bounds]];
    NSData *tiff = [bitmap TIFFRepresentation];
    [tiff writeToFile:[@"~/Desktop/snapshot.tiff" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]
           atomically:YES];
}
```

Clicking on the button to take a snapshot just results in a fully transparent image.

*Am I just completely clueless here, or is this bitmap caching method broken?*

A simple project — basically a starter NSDocument project, with a button that calls this code -- can be found [here](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1284131/bitmaptest.zip).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` doesn't actually capture anything; it just generates a blank bitmap ready for caching. You need to call `-cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:` to do that.

Comment: cacheDisplay ignores the image view if there is a high resolution image i.e 2536x 1200